# How to make someone fully attracted to me?

Tags: elona

Since talking to anyone makes them lose Attract, how do you maximize someone's Attract so you can make genes?

The Wiki just says that "Talking lowers it" and "Shopkeeper Dialogue gets less nice as it goes down". Nothing about how to raise it?

Elona+ had a patch that talked about a reset timer being changed to 12 hrs, but that's only implying that base-game Attract also has a reset timer.